# Converting Table Data Type from SQL Server to Oracle and dynamic SQL data inserting to table data type

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle11g

I've piece of code in SQL Server.

I'm trying convert it into ORACLE script. It doesn’t matter that this code translates symmetrically. The main thing is to solve the problem in native ways.

```
DECLARE @tabForTextToReplace AS TABLE (textForReplace nvarchar(200)) 

set @execSQLCommand='select top 1 '  + @viewColumnName + ' from  ' +
     @viewName + '  where obj_ID='+cast(@receiverID as varchar(50))

INSERT into @tabForTextToReplace exec sp_executesql  @execSQLCommand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I have no experience at all in TSQL, here's something in PL/SQL that looks like what you show (though the 'top 1' in your code does tell SQL to return just one row, so why inserting this into a table is beyond me):

```
declare
type t is table of nvarchar2(10);
ttab    t;
begin
select cast('123' as nvarchar2(10)) bulk collect into ttab from dual connect by level <10;
end;
/
```

Comment: yes, you are right about inserting top 1 code to table, I fixed it in MSSQL, and will try commit it to Oracle